# "wc -l" takes very long for my files, is there a faster alternative?

Tags: awk, sed, ls, wc

I need help in writing script that outputs the number of lines in each of a number of large files. `wc -l` is taking a long time, so I'm looking to use `awk` command to display the last line number for all files that match `abd*2020-09-21*`

- `ls -l abd*2020-09-21*` displays 22 long (big) files
- I need to find the `wc -l` result of each file.
- Currently im using

  ```
  wc -l abd*2020-09-21.txt > CCNC_UNIX_COUNTS.txt
  ```

  but this is very time consuming. I need help in improving it.

I tried

```
sed -n '$='
```

Now I need this to work in loop for all files matchinv `abd*2020-09-21.txt` and output the results to a file `CCNC_UNIX_COUNTS`

Comment: How big are the files that you are measuring? Are these files stored on a local disk? HDD or SDD?

Comment: It's pretty hard to beat `wc -l` for general text. Your `sed` is five times slower than `wc` in my system. Can you add a couple of lines of those files, to see how they look like?

Comment: `wc -l` was made to count newlines. It is a very hard job to beat a standard Unix tool that was born the job.

Comment: As discussed, `wc -l` is fast enough. Just if you want to test another method it can be `grep -c '\n'`.

Comment: As everyone else has commented, you're unlikely to find a command faster than `wc` for the job you have to do. Therefore, the only practical solution is `faster hardware`.

Comment: `wc -l` doesn't take a long time, however you're calling it (e.g. from a shell loop) is whats taking a long time.

Comment: @binarysta, except that that `grep` doesn't even work. `grep -c ''` would, though it would give a different answer from `wc -l` if the file ends in a line fragment without a trailing newline.

Answer (score 4):

Text files are just streams of bytes, no indexes, no metadata, just back-to-back lines with a newline (linefeed) character trailing each. There's no way to count the lines other than reading the file in full. `wc -l` can do that effectively, as it doesn't need to do anything else, just read in bulk scan for the linefeed bytes. On the other hand, `awk` and many other tools also need to look in the *contents* of the lines, to e.g. perform field splitting, and they have to interpret and execute the code you've given them to run. It's unlikely that any scripting language would be faster than `wc -l` here.

On the other hand, if the lack of metadata is often a problem, using some other file format, e.g. an SQLite database may be an option. That would of course preclude using the usual text-processing tools to process the data, but would likely make random access easier. Alternatively, if you can modify your data path to keep all lines *constant length*, random access and counting the lines are trivial (but not inserting or deleting lines in/from the middle).

Answer (score 3):

If the count does not need to be exact, then you can estimate the length by taking samples from the ends of the files, finding the mean, and calculating the number of lines based on the byte length of the file obtained with a very fast stat call.

For example, I have a 100 MB file in /tmp. Using:

```
time wc -l /tmp/100-mb.txt
```

yields:

```
1777700 /tmp/100-mb.txt
real    0m0.075s
```

Using a perl code to do the estimation:

```
time ./esmele /tmp/100-mb.txt
```

yields:

```
1763385
real    0m0.012s
```

which is accurate to better than 99% and 6 times faster. A code in C or similar might be even faster, because the translation of perl would be omitted.

Run on a system:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-10-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
perl 5.20.2
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your hardware you could try this:

**[expr-fi/fastlwc: SIMD-enhanced word counter - GitHub](https://github.com/expr-fi/fastlwc)**

There is also a multi-threaded version.

I did not bother to test it with a huge file, but it works and it *is* fast.

The alogrithm for word counting via SIMD is explained in the readme. Here is the basic idea:

```
Just a sample (multiple   spaces).
1111010111111011111111100011111111             =[1]
0111101011111101111111110001111111 SHIFT [1]   =[2]
1000010100000010000000001110000000 NOT [2]     =[3]
1000010100000010000000000010000000 [1] AND [3]
```

This `fastwc` counts words and lines, but no multibyte chars.